# Mock Objects in Android N

Tags: android, testing, mockito, robolectric, android-7.0-nougat

I'm creating a new Android project and I target to android N (with jack and Java 8). In this project I need create test, but with jack android doesn't have anymore .class file. I read because of that Mockito no longer works (or others frameworks depends class files).

So Mockito doesn't work anymore, right ? What the options to mock objects and test with Android N ? Is possible test with Robolectric in Android N ?

Thx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917993/android-jack-mockito-alternative